# NodeJS thrown error in domain stops global execution?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

Given a setup like this:

```
var domain = require('domain');

// Keep the script running, even after main context actions are done
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('Ping!');
}, 2000);

var d = domain.create();
d.on('error', function(er) {
  console.log('error', er);
  // Don't re-throw the error, to continue execution
});

var x = 0;
d.run(function() {
  x = 1;
  x = 2;
  throw new Error('Stop!');
  x = 3;
  x = 4;
  console.log('done inside domain');
});

console.log('Done!', x);
```

As expected, the thrown error is caught by the Domain's "`on('error')`" listener, and execution continues with "Ping!" messages going until you kill the process.

I expected the "done inside domain" message to never show up, but I was surprised to find that the "Done!" message and the final output of `x` wasn't shown.

If I instead use events:

```
var domain = require('domain');
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');

setInterval(function() {
  console.log('Ping!');
}, 2000);

var MyWorker = function MyWorker() {
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);
};
util.inherits(MyWorker, events.EventEmitter);

var d = domain.create();
d.on('error', function(er) {
  console.log('error', er);
});

var x = 0;
d.run(function() {
  x = 1;
  x = 2;
  var w = new MyWorker();
  w.emit('error', new Error('Stop!'));
  x = 3;
  x = 4;
  console.log('done inside domain');
});

console.log('Done!', x);
```

I get both the "done inside domain" message, and the output that X is now 4.

But what I want is for execution inside the domain to stop at that point, yet continue the outer scope after the `d.run()`. In other words, I want a "`Done! 2`" line, showing that execution in the domain stopped when `x` was 2, and that the outer context continued processing. Is that possible? I tried calling `d.dispose()` or `d.exit()` from within the `d.on('error')` listener, but that still leads to `x` being 4 and seeing the 'done inside domain' message.